# GenerateSwaggerCode task does not invalidate local cache for changes done in £ref file

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin, swagger-codegen

I'm running *gradle-swagger-generator-plugin* `GenerateSwaggerCode` task on an input yaml that contains a $refs to another file. Gradle build cache is enabled.

Task output is loaded FROM-CACHE when changes are done the referenced file.
I'm looking for a way to configure the plugin to invalidate the cache and rerun generation if changes are done in ref files.

task definition:

```
swaggerSources {
    myApi {
        inputFile = file('./api.yaml')
        code {
            language = 'spring'
            configFile = file('./swagger-config.json')
        }
    }
}
```

api.yaml:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: My api
  version: 1.0.0

host: localhost

definitions:
  MyDef:
    $ref: './another.yaml#/definitions/MyDef'
```

```
swagger.generator version : 2.18.2
swagger-codegen version: 2.4.18
gradle version: 6.8.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Specifying `code.inputs.files` in the plugin config seems to fix the problem.

https://github.com/int128/gradle-swagger-generator-plugin/issues/144